# CUDA float2 coalescing

Tags: cuda

I'm having trouble coalescing reads when using the float2 datatype in CUDA.

I've tried to make a simple example to run in the visual profiler but it always returns noncoalesced reads. If anyone could shed some light on this I would be really grateful, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

__global__ void kernel(float2 *in, float2 *out) {
        int idx=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
        float2 d=in[idx];
        d.x = 100.f;

        out[idx] = d;
}

int main() {
  const int dataSize=32;
  float2 *in;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&in,dataSize*sizeof(float2));

  float2 *out;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&out,dataSize*sizeof(float2));
  kernel<<<1,32>>>(in,out);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: which card, sm architecture ?

Comment: 8800 GTX and Compute 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question on the NVIDIA forums. Turns out loading vectors is not optimized in debug mode. [Forums](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=187641&st=0&gopid=1158150&#entry1158150)